# Where were there fractal structures in ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, art, architecture

I am looking for some examples of fractal or fractal-like structures and patterns in ancient Rome. I did some research but did not find much. On this topic I only found this article [Scipedia.com](https://www.scipedia.com/public/Md-Rian_Sassone_2014a) where the author describes a Corinthian column as an example of fractal-like object.
[image]

I would be grateful if anybody can help me and show some examples of fractals in architecture or art in ancient Rome (for instance some articles about this theme). Examples from ancient Greece are welcome as well.

(Fractals are objects or structures containing some repeating pattern which exhibit self-similarity which means that the pattern is invariant at different scales. A typical example is Mandelbrot set but fractals are present in nature as well. For instance branching trees, clouds, coastlines, mountains).

Comment: There were geometric mosaics, including the famous triskelion, so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: Neither the mosaics, not examples in your pictures are really fractals. Attention to the fractals is more recent that the ancient Rome. People just did not notice them, most of the time.

Comment: Their empire eventually **fractured**, and ultimately crumbled: does that count ?

Comment: Mosaics are good suggestion, I will take a look at them. I am not looking for exact fractals that actually exist only as math abstraction but rather  for statistical fractals in other words objects with self-similar patterns at finite number of scales.

Comment: The golden ratio is a fractal!  Used all the time in Roman architecture.

Comment: Number is not a fractal !

Answer (score -1):

The [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), or more precisely the [golden rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_rectangle) can be thought of as a fractal.

[image: How to Draw the Golden Rectangle Spiral]

Some believe that many [ancient designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_designed_with_the_golden_ratio#Greece) were built with golden rectangle in mind.

Comment: Your last link ("ancient designs") gives some possible occurences of the golden ratio in Antiquity, but not of a golden rectangle nor anything similar to a fractal...